# Find the difference between dates in a SQL Server database, in hours and calculate total hours in each day

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to sort SQL Server database data according to my project requirement. I tried many SQL queries to filter the data but none is working properly. Please do help me to complete the work.

I have a database table with 5 columns: `ProductName`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `UsageQuantity` and `Cost`. The `startdate` and `enddate` are dates with time also and they give difference of one hour if subtracted.

Likewise multiple copy of startdate and enddate are available for a month full of data. What I need is to find out the total usage and cost for one particular product per day and also like to find the sum of hours the product was used.

Can anybody suggest me the sql query or the code snippet of finding out the result?

The dates in the database looks like this

```
ProductName StartDate            EndDate              UsageQuantity Cost
 xyz        01-04-2015 00:00    01-04-2015 01:00         0.6258       .007
 sf         01-04-2015 00:00    01-04-2015 01:00
 de         01-04-2015 01:00    01-04-2015 02:00
df          01-04-2015 01:00    01-04-2015 02:00
            01-04-2015 02:00    01-04-2015 03:00
            01-04-2015 02:00    01-04-2015 03:00
            01-04-2015 03:00    01-04-2015 04:00
            01-04-2015 03:00    01-04-2015 04:00
            01-04-2015 04:00    01-04-2015 05:00
            01-04-2015 04:00    01-04-2015 05:00
            01-04-2015 05:00    01-04-2015 06:00
            01-04-2015 05:00    01-04-2015 06:00
            01-04-2015 06:00    01-04-2015 07:00
            01-04-2015 06:00    01-04-2015 07:00
```

Just help me to separate the date and time and count number of hours per day.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you have tried, it helps to make the problem clearer and it will also possibly help you see from the answers what you did wrong.

Comment: What **datatype** are your `startdate` and `enddate` in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this as a starting point

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,StartDate, EndDate)), SUM(UsageQuantity), SUM(Cost)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ProductName, Date(StartDate);
```

Comment: Assuming Date fields are dates, not strings

Comment: Should be a divide by 3600 there to change seconds to Hours - but I will leave that to you.

Comment: hi paul thank you for sharing the query.. I tried it.. but its providing the total sum of the month. i want to find per day how many hours are there in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDaysUsageForProduct
(
    @ProductName varchar(100),
    @DateUsed    datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @DateUsed DateUsed, 
           ProductName, 
           SUM(UsageQuantity) TotalQuantityUsed,
           SUM(DATEDIFF(hh, StartDate, EndDate) HoursUsed
           SUM(Cost) TotalCost
      FROM myTable
     WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), StartDate, 112) =  CONVERT(varchar(10), @Date, 112)
       AND ProductName = @ProductName
      GROUP BY ProductName

END
GO
```